# salesforce sdk login issue from android

Tags: login, loop, salesforcesdk

1)Login as user 1 ,logout and login as user 2 i see MainActivity with user 2 data now if i press back button sometimes instead of closing the app it shows the MainActivity with user 1 data.

2)Login as user 1 ,logout,login as either user 1 or 2 sometime is creates a user account in the phone with the logged in user but get into a loop of login screens.if we clear the app from history and open the app it goes to MainActivity

3)Sometimes in the Point 2 user account is not created and goes in login loop but even if the app is cleared from the history issue is not resolved two ways to resolve is force stop,clear data or uninstall and re install ﻿